# Creating an directive to spy angular life cycle hooks

Tags: angular, directive, spy, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Is there anyway to make a directive to detect every life cycle hooks like ngOnDestroy() and implements some garbage collector before the component get destroyed ?

I want to do this to avoid the component to let something run and cause memory leak

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options for

```
<app-mycomp cleanup></app-mycomp>
```

1) The directive knows its host component. So you can inject the host into the constructor

```
...
constructor(private host: MycompComponent) { }
...
```

2) and if the directive doesn't know the host. This one is a bit complex
The host component needs to provide itself

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomp',
  templateUrl: './mycomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomp.component.css'],
  providers: [{  
    provide: 'cleanable', 
    useExisting: forwardRef(()=> MycompComponent)
  }]
})
export class MycompComponent extends Cleanable implements OnInit { ... }
```

Now you can inject it as well in the directive

```
constructor(@Inject('cleanable') private host: Cleanable) { ... }
```

Finally, in the directive you can define the life cycle hooks.

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4r6cm9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbarfoo%2Fbarfoo.component.ts)